# Is it okay to keep my margs as 0.9 inch instead of 1 inch for my SOP

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, undergraduate, statement-of-purpose

My SOP is extending the general 2 page limit by exactly 2 lines.

Will it be okay if use a 0.9inch margin (all sides) instead of 1inch? I am using an overleaf template so all the other norms are being followed.

I am asking because then it will be exactly 2-pages.

Comment: Sorry, but we have no way of knowing the formatting requirements of every university in the world...

Comment: Assuming it is 1inch, will 0.9inch be noticeable?

Comment: Your university mandates formats for standard operating procedures?

Comment: I think it's only a soft constraint, there is no hard and fast rule.

Comment: I think Azor's point is that you didn't define SOP. I assume you mean "statement of purpose."

Comment: @cag51 Actually I've just been reading a lot of standard operating procedures and just thought that's what the OP meant.

Comment: Yes I meant statement of purpose, Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may or may not be noticed. It may or may not be important. No one but the recipient can say for sure. You don't want a reader to be irritated with you.

So, I have a suggestion for you. First reformat it to the required standard. Then rewrite it to fit the two page limit if that is required. You will probably gain from being just a bit more concise in your wording. Don't just make it awkward. Rethink your phrasing and be more precise.

Less is More.